# Lockd Freezes once or more per day

Tags: server, kernel, nfs

Server has been running for over 1.5 years, with no problem.
Last week started receiving errors and workstations freeze:
lockd: cannot monitor 
statd: server rpc.statd not responding, timed out

Server:
OS: Ubuntu 10.04.4
Kernel: Linux  2.6.32-51-server
nfs-common                      1:1.2.0-4ubuntu4.2
nfs-kernel-server               1:1.2.0-4ubuntu4.2 
/home   x.x.x.0/255.255.0.0(rw,no_root_squash,insecure,async,wdelay,no_subtree_check)
/public x.x.x.0/255.255.0.0(rw,no_root_squash,insecure,async,wdelay,no_subtree_check)

Workstations:
Ubuntu 10.04.x
server:/home    /home       nfs defaults 0 0
server:/public  /mnt/public nfs defaults 0 0

Ran rpcinfo -p both from workstations and from servers both return ok.

While lockd frozen, server is 100% accessible i.e ssh top df all return as expected.
However the workstations are unable to move between desktops and become unresponsive, chrome stops functioning

On server ps -aux | grep lockd shows that the lockd process is D.
However after a couple of min lockd returns to S and R, and workstations are functional again

After enabling nlm_debug I see that indeed the lockd process gets stuck

I notice in the below log that the lockd gets stuck for a minute 02:03:21 -- 02:04:21

This repeats when the lockd gets stuck and I found that by rebooting the "offending" workstation
the all systems return to function normally.

```
Oct  2 02:04:21 fs1 kernel: [647001.312596] lockd: request from 172.x.x.x, port=960
Oct  2 02:04:21 fs1 kernel: [647001.312603] lockd: LOCK          called
Oct  2 02:03:21 fs1 kernel: [646941.418685] lockd: nlmsvc_lookup_host(host='roi-lnx', vers=4, proto=tcp)
Oct  2 02:03:21 fs1 kernel: [646941.418687] lockd: get host roi-lnx
Oct  2 02:03:21 fs1 kernel: [646941.418688] lockd: nlm_lookup_host found host roi-lnx (172.16.16.76)
Oct  2 02:03:21 fs1 kernel: [646941.418689] lockd: nsm_monitor(roi-lnx)
Oct  2 02:04:21 fs1 kernel: [647001.312552] statd: server rpc.statd not responding, 
timed out
Oct  2 02:04:21 fs1 kernel: [647001.312565] lockd: NSM upcall RPC failed, status=-5
Oct  2 02:04:21 fs1 kernel: [647001.312570] lockd: cannot monitor roi-lnx
Oct  2 02:04:21 fs1 kernel: [647001.312572] lockd: release host roi-lnx
```

This looks like a bug in lockd.

I have spent days looking though Google, and there are a couple of similar cases but no fixes.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions to resolve this issue.

Thanks
Laurence

Answer (score 1):

In a similar environment with 10.04.4 ubuntu nfs-server serving approx. 50 ubuntu/mac os x clients (mostly 12.04.3), I had the same problem. The clients were only working when mounted the home-directories with the nolock option (which one shouldn't do).

After debugging all possible stuff in the network for two weeks a realized after finding [this on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/527463/desperate-statd-timed-out-lockd-cannot-monitor-unmonitor), that the only change was including two new clients (12.04.3) with kernel 3.8.0-29-generic running. After taken these two out of the network (actually yesterday), the statd and lockd are stable again on the server.

I will report what happens today, once all clients will be in full operation again.

Is there any new client in your network?

Comment: Downgrading the kernel to 3.2.0-54 really solved the problem.

Comment: upgrade from 3.13.0-40-generic to .13.0-43-generic also solve this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar experience in a 4-node cluser where all of the nodes are using 3.2.0-38-generic under ubuntu 12.04.5. The nfs version is:

```
dpkg -la | grep nfs
ii  libnfsidmap2                       0.25-1ubuntu2               NFS idmapping     library
ii  nfs-common                         1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3.2                                  NFS support files common to client and server
ii  nfs-kernel-server                  1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3.2                                  support for NFS kernel server
```

It is found one of the problematic node is constantly "attacking the NFS server". Once the problematic node is taken out from the system, no hangs occures again.